# Not able to update using VF page in custom controller

Tags: visualforce, controller

I'm writing simple class, which has to insert or update  few fields of account

Getting following error  :

> MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call:

Getting this error on this line : update acc ;

```
public class ctrAccountCustom {
Public Account acc = new Account(); 


Public void setAcc(Account a)
 {
  acc = a;
 }

public Account GetAcc()
 {
   Return [Select id, name, industry from Account where ID= : ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
 }



  //Custom Save function in custom Controller

   public PageReference SaveValues() {


     If (ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id')!= null)  
      {      
        if(acc!= null)
        update acc ;
      }
    else
        insert acc;
   return null;
}
}
```

**Corresponding VF page :**

```
<apex:page controller="ctrAccountCustom">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
     <apex:pageblockSection >
      <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Name}" />
      <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Industry}" />
     </apex:pageblockSection> 
     <apex:pageblockButtons >
         <apex:commandButton action="{!SaveValues}" value="Save Current Record"/>
     </apex:pageblockButtons>
     </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I've tried adding vf page code lines but somehow code is not getting added in the block above

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
  //Custom Save function in custom Controller

   public PageReference SaveValues() {
     if (ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id')!= null) {      
        acc = getAcc();

        update acc;
    } else
        insert acc;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks for hint.  i'm not getting that error now . But now Modified information ( e.g new name, industry) are not getting saved. It seems evident -as I'm getting original record using acc  = getAcc() statement.                                                          so new  modified information is not available to 'Custom Save' function(SaveValues())   . My question is what my setter function is doing in this case?  Does it not setting account with updated information ?

Comment: You need to remove the `if` block. See my updated answer

Comment: This is still not doing update

Comment: Are you sure you get an Account with your query ?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
add = getAcc();
```

in your if-statement. Right now your `acc` is just `new Account()`, so this record doesn't even exist

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to update non existing Account. 
Below code snippet executes event Account is not available.

```
If (ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id')!= null)  
      {      
        if(acc!= null)
        update acc ;
      }
if(acc!=null) - is always true as you are initializing account at class level.
You can do something like this:
if(acc!=null && acc.id!=null){
   update acc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below statement to get Account Id from Parameters

> ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().put('id',acc.id);